# How to store extracted fearure points from imageframes in SQLlite (Android)

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, computer-vision, feature-detection

How do i store the extracted feature points from an imageframe in SQLlite database in android ?. 
I am able to detect and extract feature points successfully in NDK using C++, now i want to store these feature points and later use it for comparison with feature points detected in camera.

Here is the sample code i plan to work on

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALLJava_org_opencv_samples_tutorial2_Tutorial2Activity_FindFeatures(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba)

{
Mat& mGr  = *(Mat*)addrGray;
Mat& mRgb = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
cv::Mat descriptor;

vector<KeyPoint> v;

cv::OrbFeatureDetector detector;
cv::OrbDescriptorExtractor extractor;
detector.detect(mGr, v);

extractor.compute(mGr,v,descriptor);

    {
    // code for storing the feature points
    }
    }
Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial2_Tutorial2Activity_MatchFeatures(JNIEnv*, jobject, jlong addrGray, jlong addrRgba)
{
Mat& mGr  = *(Mat*)addrGray;
Mat& mRgb = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
cv::Mat descriptor;

vector<KeyPoint> v1;

cv::OrbFeatureDetector detector1;
cv::OrbDescriptorExtractor extractor1;
detector1.detect(mGr, v1);

extractor1.compute(mGr,v1,descriptor1);
{
// code for fetching the feature points from database
}
    cv::BFMatcher matcher1;

    std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
matcher1.match({descriptor extracted from database},descriptor1,matches);

 // here comes code for finding good matches by ratio test  and Homograpgy 
}
```

Can somebody please explain how store and extract feature points from database in android.

Comment: All that code is not very relevant for this question. Try to improve your question, make it shorter and more to the point and maybe someone will answer!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @RuiMarques .But i am not planning on storing the feature points in database any more. I am using a xml file to do this. By the way i very frequently visit your google plus page , nice information on recent CV stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I am glad you appreciate it :)